# Eleven Paris font indentification

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can you identify these fonts or something extremely close to them?

[image: t-shirt font]

Eleven Paris T-Shirt, Karl is My Father Collection

[image: logo font]

 Eleven Paris website

Comment: Please edit your question to follow our [font id requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611). Otherwise your question will likely get closed!

Answer (score 1):

The block font on the T-Shirt is pretty close to [Jersey M54](http://www.dafont.com/jersey-m54.font?text=KARL%20IS%20MY%20FATHER):

[image]

The typeface used in the Eleven Paris logo can probably be easily tracked down with some of the resources listed in the [font ID requirements found here.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) Alternatively, if you know the website this logo comes from, try inspecting the site for the same font.
 *Hint:* They most definitely use it elsewhere on there.

Also, please include only one font identification request per question.